# Procedure or function 'userpro' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, asp.net

i am getting error of ExcecuteNonQuery ,i am not getting where i am wrong please help!

```cs
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
   "Data Source="";Initial Catalog=bunny;Integrated Security=SSPI");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("userpro", con);
CommandType cd = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addresss", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact ", TextBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", TextBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwords", TextBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPassword", TextBox6.Text);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

this is my store procedure

```
 create procedure userpro

 @Username varchar (20),
 @Addresss varchar (20),
 @Contact varchar (20),
 @EmailId varchar (20),
 @Passwords varchar (20),
 @ConfirmPassword varchar (20)
 as
 begin
 if exists (select * from userlogs where Username=@Username)
 begin
update userlogs set     Addresss=@Addresss,Contact=@Contact,EmailId=@EmailId,Passwords=@Passwords,ConfirmPassword=@ConfirmPassword where Username=@Username                   
end
else
begin
insert into     userlogs(Username,Addresss,Contact,EmailId,Passwords,ConfirmPassword) values    (@Username,@Addresss,@Contact,@EmailId,@Passwords,@ConfirmPassword)
end
end
```

Comment: Check this CommandType cd = CommandType.StoredProcedure; in your code. And you are using cmd in your code instead of cd.

Comment: Using parameters is a good start, but you may want to read [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: `Data Source=""` why double quotes ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if TextBox1.Text is not null. If it is procedure will fail because @Username is mandatory. You can resolve this like that:

```
if(TextBox1.Text == null)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", DBNull.Value); 
else
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox1.Text);
```

Or you can make this parameter optional in your userpro procedure:

```
create procedure userpro

   @Username varchar (20) = '',
```